# getting error "Invalid value" when trying to use secret value in flux Kustomization patchesStrategicMerge

Tags: kubernetes, flux

I am getting the error

```
dry-run failed, reason: Invalid, error: Deployment.apps "server" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[0].valueFrom: Invalid value:
"": may not be specified when `value` is not empty
```

when trying to override a value in *flux Kustomization* using `patchesStrategicMerge` like:

```
  env:
  - name: DATABASE_URL
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: server-db-url
        key: dburl
```

The secret `server-db-url` exists and contains the key `dburl`

I am not sure if this has something to do with https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/46861

Comment: Could you please provide more details on how you set up your cluster? What Kubernetes/flux version are using? Could you provide the entire yaml file without private information?

Comment: Did you figure it out ?

Answer (score 4):

As workaround (mentioned in github issue you linked) you can add "value: null" to configuration:

```
  env:
  - name: DATABASE_URL
    value: null
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: server-db-url
        key: dburl
```

Comment: When i use this, i get the following error env[0].valueFrom: Invalid value: "": may not be specified when `value` is not empty (v1.23.1)

Answer (score 3):

The reason might be that Kubernetes API ran into a conflict. Most likely, in your **"running/current"** deployment `DATABASE_URL` already has a hardcoded value. Try removing `DATABASE_URL` from environment variables.

Comment: This was my issue - I had edited my deployment to temporarily use a hardcoded value instead of a secret, then my next deployment failed. Editing the current deployment back to using a secret allowed the new deployment to succeed! Thanks :)